# How can i get WPF built-in localized strings?

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a WPF application which has custom title bar( custom Minimize, Maximinze and Close button). These buttons have tool tip strings need be localized. but, i think .net/WPF already has these strings localized for all languages, I don't want to do it myself, so is it possible to get these string from WPF built-in resources? and, How can i do it?

[image]
How can i get string "Maximize" from WPF built-in resources？ so it  can change with OS locale language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WPF doesn't have copies of these strings. It simply delegates painting the default window chrome to the OS, which handles displaying the tooltips along with everything else.

And unfortunately, there is no Windows API that allows one to retrieve localized strings. I suppose you could extract them from the system files, but I don't recommend it. They're not documented as being publically accessible and the details of the implementation are therefore subject to change at any time.

I'm not sure why you're against adding these strings to your resource table. You've already re-invented more of the wheel than I'd recommend by painting custom window chrome. If you absolutely must do so, then you're going to have to handle everything yourself, including the tooltip strings. If the default strings would work, and you have all of the same buttons in the same positions, then there's no point in painting custom chrome in the first place.

Comment: If you choose to discard the chrome provided by the OS, you discard all of it. You better make sure you _really_ want it.